# Strange error on first startup Backendless

Tags: android, backendless

I'm trying to run my app with Backendless for the first time. I recieve this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/backendless/BackendlessCollection;
    at com.backendless.Persistence.<init>(Persistence.java:72)
    at com.backendless.Persistence.<clinit>(Persistence.java:62)
    at com.backendless.Persistence.getInstance(Persistence.java:66)
    at com.backendless.Backendless.<clinit>(Backendless.java:43)
    at com.asd.asd.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:89)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.backendless.BackendlessCollection" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.asd.asd.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.asd.asd.android-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

The stacktrace gives me no clue on what may be wrong since I don't even use the BackendlessCollection class. 
The error points at:

```
Backendless.initApp(this,app_ID,android_ID, version_id);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a known issue in Backendless, it has been fixed in their newer SDK. Here`s link on maven central http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.backendless/backendless/3.0.8.1